# Why does my MacBook Pro macOS 10.14.1 system storage oscillate so drastically (75 GB to 150 GB)?

Tags: hard-drive

As question says, I have an older MacBook Pro (purchased 2013) running macOS 10.14.1. My computer has 500 GB of storage space. My free space lately has been oscillating between 5 GB and 75 GB because the system storage is oscillating between 80 GB and 150 GB.

What is going on in system storage that's causing it to oscillate so drastically, and how do I stop it from doing that? Already once it started to prevent me from saving things because it said there wasn't enough space available, and then after I restarted and waited about an hour, I was back up to 75 GB of free space. It sometimes oscillates back and forth multiple times per day.

Comment: could it the disk is failing ? did you try `fsck`

Comment: where do you see the oscillation ?

Comment: I haven't tried 'fsck' yet. Googled it, and Google told me to do Disk Utility first. I'll run that later.

The oscillation is entirely in "system". It goes from a minimum of 80 GB to a maximum of about 150 GB and oscillates between the two. It's been sitting at 135 GB for the last hour, plus or minus 5 GB.

Comment: use About this Mac > Storage > Mange to get clearer picture what is going on.

Comment: That's where I'm getting the information from. It doesn't give a breakdown of "system" storage. It just says, "System: 135.36 GB" right now.

Comment: I did not know that, you did not disclose it. when did the problem start ? FYI my system is 60GB. Looking in Activity Monitor > Disk...who is most active there

Comment: For ("bytes written"/"bytes read"), it's kernel_task (1.09 TB / 75 GB), launchd (445 GB / 5GB), mds_stores (87 GB / 109 GB), coresymbolicationd (11 GB / 1.85 GB), Amazon Photos (6 GB / 16 GB), and Firefox (5 GB / 15 GB). The rest are <1 GB. The "coresymbolicationd bytes written" one increased by 0.5 GB as I typed this.

Comment: we are just trying to figure out if it is your disk failing or someone writing to it. Considering the age the kernel looks ok, the launchd is bit high , and the mds (which is spotlight) is on high end.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to the spotlight part, but there are a lot of files on this computer because it was my research laptop. I just counted the files in the user folder. There are 1,161,171 files. 

I'll run the First Aid on the Disk Utility app soon, as I'm about to head out for a couple of hours.

Thanks, Buscar!

Comment: good luck ...........

Comment: The Disk Utility thing didn't seem to fix anything judging by its outputs, although I am up to 96 GB free space and down to 63 GB in "system" space, which are better than before. I assume it'll continue to oscillate though.

Comment: remember we are trying to find out if your disk is dying or something is writing to it. Try to reset the Finder just in case. Hold Option key and right click on Finder icon in Doc, then use Relaunch.